# Nested For Loop Controlling speed

Tags: arduino-mega

I have a servo motor That I am trying to determine the delay speed in between pulses with a nested for loop. This issue is instead of running together like 0,0 1,1 2,2 its actually going up like 0,0 0,1 0,2. SO the first for loop i will only go up once all of the x for loop goes to its max 255.

What I want it to do is go up together until x reaches 255 and then it will stabilize there as I will countering to climb.

If any know anything about nested for loop I would appreciated (please only add valuable comment or help to this. I don't need pointless or dumb comments (talking about  jsotola and all he did was criticized my question)

```
 for (int i=0; i<500; i++)    
  {
      for( int x=0; x<255; x++){

    digitalWrite(DIR,LOW);
    digitalWrite(PUL,HIGH);
    Serial.print("i = ");
    Serial.println(i);
    Serial.print("x = ");
    Serial.println(x);
    delayMicroseconds(x);
    digitalWrite(PUL,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(x);
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are nested loops:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 255; x++) {
        do_something_with(i, x);
    }
}
```

“Nested loops” means you have a loop within a loop: within each
iteration of the outer loop you get a full run of the inner loop. The
sequence of (i, x) pairs is:

```
(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), ... (0, 254)
(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), ... (1, 254)
...
(499, 0), (499, 1), ...     (499, 254)
```

> What I want it to do is go up together until x reaches 255 and then it
>   will stabilize there as I will countering to climb.

This sentence is not very clear. I assume you mean that you want the
following sequence of (i, x) pairs:

```
(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), ... (255, 255),
(256, 255), (257, 255), ... (499, 255)
```

If this is what you want, you can more easily achieve it with a single
loop:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    int x = min(i, 255);
    do_something_with(i, x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help!
This worked.